# Find a counterexample weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Prove it or falsify/give a counterexample:

If $f_j \rightharpoonup f $ and $f_j \rightarrow g $ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then $f=g$.

It sounds wrong but I do not find any counterexample... I am thankful for every hint or answer :)

Comment: Try to prove that $f_j \to f$ implies $f_j \rightharpoonup f$.

Comment: ok this is pretty simple: Every element of the dual space $(L^2)^*$ is a bounded linear functional and therefore is continuous. So weak convergence follows from definition...

Comment: weak limits are unique?

Comment: Of course, try to prove :3

Comment: assume not: then for one $f \in X^*$ we have $f(x)\neq f(y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are different weak limits. but $f(x_n) \rightarrow  f(x)$ and the same for the other. But these strong limits must be unique. thats a contradiction, right?

Comment: Right, but you need to prove that such $f$ exist; for example its not true in general for metric spaces, that for every pair of points $x,y \in M$ we have continuous functional $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \not = f(y)$. Why we can separate points by functional in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: is it riesz????

Answer (score 2):

We show weak limits are unique in a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose $w_n \to w$ weakly and $w_n \to w'$ weakly. Then, for any $v \in H$, $\langle w,v \rangle = \lim_n \langle w_n,v \rangle = \langle w',v \rangle$. Thus, for all $v \in H$, $\langle w-w' ,v \rangle = 0 \implies w=w'$.

This proof would work in any Banach space, using the Hahn Banach theorem to get a linear functional that separates points.

Comment: thanks alot but I do not understand the point with application of hahn banach and separate points. could you please say something more to this?

Comment: Sure. So the definition of weak convergence is that $x_n \to x$ weakly if for every continuous linear functional $l$, $l(x_n) \to l(x)$. The proof I gave for the Hilbert space is implicitly using the fact that all linear functionals are inner products (this is one of the Riesz representation theorems).

Comment: For an arbitrary Banach space $X$, if $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \to y$ both weakly, then take some $l \in X^*$ with $l(x) \not = l(y)$. Then we get a contradiction since $l(x_n) \to l(x), l(y)$.